How is it possible to unhide P2SB device in PCI configuration space?
I have an Intel 300-series chipset and I have been trying to unlock P2SB device for a long time. If you do a quick search on Google, you will find people saying that all you need is to write 0s to 0:31:1 (Bus:Device:Function) in PCI.
I have tried to do that using the mm command in EFI shell, and I have also tested the RW everything command WPCI.
WPCI 0 31 1 0xE0 0

None of these methods worked for me, P2SB device remains hidden
